# Run query when in while loop nodejs not occuring

Tags: node.js

Hi i am running the while loop however the while loop is not running the block in the second line after`console.log("In while loop")`

this is the whole section

```
router.post("/", function(req,res,next){
  router.use(bodyParser.json());
  let tag_id = generate_tag();
  let tag_id_correct = false;
  while(tag_id_correct != true){
    console.log("in while loop");
    res.locals.connection.query("SELECT Tag_ID from trakk_items WHERE Tag_ID = '" + tag_id +"'", function (error, results, fields){
      console.log("WE ARE IN");
      if (error) {
        res.send(JSON.stringify({
          "status": 500,
          "error": error,
          "response": null
        }));
      }
      else{
        tag_id_correct = true;
        console.log(tag_id_correct);
      }
      console.log(results);
      res.send(JSON.stringify({
        "response" : results
      }));
    });
  }
  console.log("unique tagid created");

});

module.exports = router;
```

any suggestions

Thanks

Comment: There's a lot of things wrong with your code, clear some things up for me please so I can help you. What is exactly you want to achieve? Respond with valid tags?, generate an unique tag?

Comment: Hi generate a unique tag witch is not already in my db

Comment: And insert it in the DB in that route? If so I don't see any insert.

Comment: It inserts it with some other data from the body of the request

Comment: It will then* meant to go at beginning sorry